# Python、replaceを使ってデータセットのカンマの削除を行う場合「複数カラムの選択方法」と「すべてのカラムの選択方法」を教えてください

Tags: python

**質問内容**
pythonでデータフレームの数値がobjectになっているため
数値化しようとしています。
その前処理として、すべての列の数値のカンマを削除したいの
ですがどのように書けばよろしいか教えてください。

**試したこと**
1つの列ごとであれば以下のコードで削除できました。

```
df["A"]=df["A"].str.replace(",","")
df.head()
```

[image]

**知りたいこと**
replaceを使った場合の
・複数列の指定方法
・データセットすべての選択方法

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「データフレーム」というのはおそらく Pandas の機能のことだと思いますが，Python 本体にはそのような概念がないので，重要な前提事項に関する説明が欠落している気がします．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'A': [ 3069,  8390,  6378,  6236,  4486],
  'B': [  '425', '9,154', '3,157', '7,052', '6,798'],
  'C': ['2,401', '2,526', '8,541', '7,426', '9,082'],
  'D': [ 7017,  4678,   465,  1298,  6169],
})

dfx = df.copy()
dfx[['B', 'C']] = dfx[['B', 'C']].replace(',', '', regex=True)
print(dfx)

dfx = df.copy()
dfx = dfx.replace(',', '', regex=True)
print(dfx)

#
      A     B     C     D
0  3069   425  2401  7017
1  8390  9154  2526  4678
2  6378  3157  8541   465
3  6236  7052  7426  1298
4  4486  6798  9082  6169

      A     B     C     D
0  3069   425  2401  7017
1  8390  9154  2526  4678
2  6378  3157  8541   465
3  6236  7052  7426  1298
4  4486  6798  9082  6169
```